# html2canvas border radius not applying to img tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, canvas, html5-canvas

Need help, when i apply border radius to imgae via css, it is not rendering properly, rendered image should be same preview image. I used html2canvas to convert div to image.

Attached image for reference, first one is normal preview with border-radius and 2nd one without border-radius.

[image]

```
<div id="mydiv">
<img src="1.jpg" /> 
<p>text!</p>
</div>

<p>Generated image</p>
<div id="image">
<p>Image:</p>
</div>
```

CSS

```
    <style>
    #mydiv {
    width: 300px;
    height: 200px;
    background:#000;


}
#mydiv img {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    border-radius:100%;


}

    </style>
```

js

```
html2canvas([document.getElementById('mydiv')], {
    onrendered: function (canvas) {
        //document.getElementById('canvas').appendChild(canvas);
        var data = canvas.toDataURL('image/png');
        // AJAX call to send `data` to a PHP file that creates an image from the dataURI string and saves it to a directory on the server

        var image = new Image();
        image.src = data;
        document.getElementById('image').appendChild(image);
    }
});
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**This is an unresolved bug (the issue has been reported):**

http://github.com/niklasvh/html2canvas/issues/346

**You can use the clipping capability of canvas as a workaround.**

A Demo:  http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/8wL2q/

[image]

Example code using a clipping area instead of border radius:

```
// save the context in its unaltered state
ctx.save();

// fill canvas with black
ctx.fillStyle="black";
ctx.fillRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);

// create clipping region which will display portion of image
// The image will only be visible inside the circular clipping path
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.arc(100,100,100,0,Math.PI*2);
ctx.closePath();
ctx.clip();

// draw the image into the clipping region
ctx.drawImage(img,0,0);

// restore the context to its unaltered state
ctx.restore();
```

Comment: Reported link in jsFiddle is seperate issue, and now they resolved it, and my issue is border radius at image via css. Currently if you take image as background in css and apply border radius it will work fine, but by calling image div and apply border radius via, it will not work. Nevertheless i will use your code for time been, untill they find some solution, Thanks

Answer (score -1):

use `border: solid windowtext 1.0pt;`instead of `border:1px solid #fff;`in css